# What's the formal answer to a question beginning with "Shall we"?

Tags: phrase-usage

I've been asked "Shall we chat then?".

The automatic affirmative answer that I would give is "Yes, let's." But in this case, the email conversation is a bit more formal, and I feel my go-to answer would be a bit too informal in the emails' context. (An alternative "Yes, please" that works for most "shall we" questions is also rather an unfitting reply in this case, I think.)

Is there a (bit) more formal way to say "yes" in response to a "shall we" (without sounding like a mock reply, such as "Yes, we shall")?

Help, please!

Comment: *Let's do that* would fit nicely, since in combines a common response with the first person plural (we and us) used it the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think *Yes, let's* is a perfectly good answer here (that is, I don't believe it is any less "formal" than the use of the word "shall" by the questioner).

But, to avoid using that phrase, I think something like *Absolutely* would work (though it is a bit emphatic). You could also say *That would be great* or *I would like that* if the affirmative answer depends at all on your own opinion of the idea of chatting.